# Why does this base64 string decode online and not locally

Tags: base64, jwt

I have a base64 encoded JWT that decodes on jwt.io and on base64decode.org but does not decode using base64 command on my OSX not my Linux machine (running echo {the string} | grep base64 --decode.  I have no idea why, here is the string:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.NJ9jflW7Hk_RLL8X7olwvxeSl6bdeO783_iOkLegBcocZCP-0szh3kZ45gG3WAGN6O2KERuyg7lVGz1b5PT7CpaOyBGTGMYZDN6H6mqqs4EUidS10OV7191rYxLy0xh5axdw4O9Oci3fUL8U8ueO0AUNVomb_Tdw-3Ncgi7e35wmxv-PZiPe6fs_1aldy3BCCs4nZxV6cu8DeOmBRYuSC8qzYwmwZvWAlj_JAOOOT_1xvG8zQ6YUGPrNreADKZhVnbksjfGBee3fE3GjcFK8Sd1dbwap2hcw0n-FX-2PPK2IqLLeEdrOK1KcaxwHSfCupPGvXQa9ga03GMRhyd95Q9uZ6nSt2UijMEglCCQzSMKMQykriBsAD3_gQ375UnrXwzFdo6qfBWrNiBOuQiHN2E5XqMpRk1GYBH1K1cf8wp1ninGX4kJP6jbIGkAwNlsE0sLeXifUV0SLBHwEEFreq6BjLyXrWnmhXUPMoQOa-07zwx5iypwSSSr_o6x2xsEjKtJWA6kau_uArEfS7fYpTqKrOpZhPMZyrk5LojLgAnsPEgoDmm0PxMDDPaDSExXGwwDDumOw5UDrgoSp6Holt0XJ9sV1N2Jy7uoKCT6268ovIHOwjsrAKugNJAfGRYuxAzT9Dr5R3wxxZxw571yLAxitA_5fZeejgqZqrZ1MaII
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is not properly encoded base64. You have periods, underscores and hyphens in there.

I was able to clean up your string
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

That decodes fine in https://www.developertoolkits.com/base64/decoder

Comment: Interesting.  Did you clean this up manually? If the original string is not properly base64 encoded do you know why base64decode.org and jwt.io successfully decode it?

Comment: Yes I visually just removed the invalid characters. No idea why the other site decoded it. They POST the data to their server. Presumably they strip out invalid base64 characters before decoding.

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is that you're trying to decode the full JWT in a single hit. The [JWT specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-13) says that a JWT is three `.` separated base64 encoded pieces.

If you split the string on the two dots then each of the three pieces do decode using standard command line tools. The earlier poster is correct that underscores and hyphens are not valid in pure base64 encoding, but there are variants and some do allow these characters so provided you are following a consistent strategy those characters are fine.

Answer (score 1):

[@Gary Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6916419/gary-lloyd) is right in that because JWT format is [`<header>.<payload>.<signature>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Structure) and `.` is not part of base64, that causes `base64` command to error out with `invalid input`.
What's more is that JWT format for `<header>`, `<payload>`, and `<signature>` are base64URL which is slight modification of `base64`.
Another note is that if you try to decode `<signature>`, it inherently has all kinds of funny characters(maybe binary?) which will fail if you try decoding it.

All that said, try separating the `<header>` and `<payload>` and it should decode just fine.

Here's a simple bash script that you can add in your `bashrc` file if you really want to use cli.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function base64jwt() {
  read content
  token_parts=($(echo "$content" | tr "." "\n"))
  echo "[$(base64 -d <<< "$token_parts[1]"), $(base64 -d <<< "$token_parts[2]")]"
}
```

Note that I added the content in an array format `[<header_content>, <payload_content>]` so that you can easily pipe that to tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for prettier json format.

e.g.

```
echo "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG5Eb2UiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9.RW7PfdmXPU5baGCV2WIXosKpuahEMUUY4nJvEh7gLDo" \
| base64jwt \
| jq
```